# How do you replace the files in a folder using Group Policy Preferences?

Tags: windows-server-2008, group-policy

Our users have a toolbar on their Windows taskbar called "I Need Help".  It holds links to our support system with specific fields prefilled.  We've changed some of the structure our our support system and need to replace the links inside the folder.  Some of the links have different names and some are being completely removed.  Ideally we just want to clear the folder and replace it with a new set of files.

What's the best way to do this through Group Policy Preferences in Windows Server 2008?

Comment: I tried to do this, but gave up and used a script + robocopy. Scheduled it with GPP tho. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I've got to go with Bård's suggestion. Instead of asking myself "What's the easiest way to do task *x* with tool *z*?", I'd ask myself "what's the easiest way to do task *x*?". A nice little login script or scheduled task script that just does a straight xcopy/robocopy/etc would be my weapon of choice here. Add a test to check if one of the new files exists or something like that and exit if so to add a bit of intelligence to the process, and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Where are the files located?  It would be very simple if the toolbar pointed to a network share, that way you would only need to replace the files once and you were done.  If the files are local, then I suggest creating a logon script that will copy the files from a central repository to the local directory.  You could tell the script to mimic deletions as well.

Comment: The files need to be copied locally because they may not be on the network when "They need help".  We currently use We currently use Computer Configuration > Preferences > Windows Settings > Files to push the files via GP.  However, this is the first time we've needed to change the content in the folder.

Comment: If they're not on the network when the need help how do they access the support system?

Comment: The support system is web based.  They can reach it from anywhere with an internet connection.  They only have to log into the network one time to get the links.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a toolbar (drag folder to edge method) or the way you have it, but like other people pointed out, use network files. Then also have a rule to use offline files on that folder so users get the latest when they're on the network and have a copy when they're off.